# DropDownListFor - need help defining "SelectedValue" property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I need help understanding how to set the `SelectedValue` property in `HTML.DropDownListFor`.

Here's what I have so far:
In another part of the model, MA is an `int` that is stored on the database.

In the Model:

```
public IList<SelectListItem> SelectListMA(int MA)
    {
        
        IList < SelectListItem > List = new List<SelectListItem>();
        SelectListItem Item;
        for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            Item = new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = i.ToString(),
                Text = i.ToString(),
                Selected = i == MA
            };
            List.Add(Item);
        }
        return List;
    }
```

In the controller:

```
ViewBag.MA = _Repository.SelectListMA(5);
```

And finally, in the View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MA, new SelectList(ViewBag.MA, dataValueField: "Value", dataTextField: "Text"))
```

In the View the dropdown displays fine, however the default value is not being set and I am using the model to pass the original model for editing to `View` hence using `ViewBag`

**Edit: Further details Requested - this is the full Controller that this belongs to.**

```
    private readonly IRacesRepos _RaceRepository;

    public BaseTeamsController(IRacesRepos _Repository)
    {
        _RaceRepository = _Repository;


    }
    //sets the Model to the repository
    public BaseTeamsController() : this(new ModelRaces()) { }
        

    public ActionResult BEditPlayer(int ID)
        {
    
            Races_Players SelectedPlayer = _RaceRepository.GetPlayerBase(ID);
    
    
            ViewBag.MA = _RaceRepository.SelectListMA(SelectedPlayer.MA);
    
            ViewBag.ST = _RaceRepository.SelectListST(SelectedPlayer.ST);
            ViewBag.AG = _RaceRepository.SelectListAG(SelectedPlayer.AG);
            ViewBag.PA = _RaceRepository.SelectListPA((int)SelectedPlayer.PA);
            ViewBag.AV = _RaceRepository.SelectListAV(SelectedPlayer.AV);
            ViewBag.Race = _RaceRepository.GetRaceBase(SelectedPlayer.RaceID);
            return View(SelectedPlayer);
        }
```

And I am using MVC version 5, and ModelRaces is the name of the model that contains the code, MA is an int in the model from the database.

Full View

```
@model BB2020MVC.Models.Races_Players

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add Player to " + ViewBag.RaceName;
}



@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Add Player to @ViewBag.RaceName</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PlayerID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RaceID)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10 focus">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MA, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MA, new SelectList(ViewBag.MA, dataTextField: "Text", dataValueField:"Value") , new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MA, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ST, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ST, new SelectList(ViewBag.ST, dataTextField: "Text", dataValueField: "Value"), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ST, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AG, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AG, new SelectList(ViewBag.AG, dataTextField: "Text", dataValueField: "Value"), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AG, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PA, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PA, new SelectList(ViewBag.PA, dataTextField: "Text", dataValueField: "Value") ,new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PA, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AV, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AV, new SelectList(ViewBag.AV, dataTextField: "Text", dataValueField: "Value") ,new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AV, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cost, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cost, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cost, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>




    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MaxQTY, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MaxQTY, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MaxQTY, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "ViewRace", new { ID = Model.RaceID })
</div>
```

Edit: Been doing a bit of testing and reading, issue seems to be that the view is not selecting the selected value of `model => model.MA` yet the value is not null on editing so any value that has been selected by `SelectListItem` or `SelectList` is ignored.
Also passing any value into `selectedValue` other than a number or word (eg "1" or "Word", not a variable of type int or string) causes the item to not be selected.
Doesn't fix the issue but an interesting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this one lies between the keyboard and the screen.

Let me explain:

In the additional testing I had erroneously changed `_RaceRepository.GetPlayerBase(ID)` to another function that generates a new base for the record. (an impromptu Mutation Test!)

This meant every time I was trying to edit the player, I was passing the default value of "1 to the view and upon submission edited a model that never existed in the first place.

Upon setting the correct function, I was getting the correct values and thus the setting of the selected value sorted itself out.

I will however thank Sergey for having a look and trying to assist, and providing a better way of providing a SelectList (A better version would be to use a ViewModel, that will have to be used for another part).

So for those that are interested, here is the code that solves this issue:

From the Model:

```
public SelectList SelectListMA()
    {
        IList<SelectListItem> List = new List<SelectListItem>();
        SelectListItem Item;
        for(int i = 1; i <=9; i++)
        {
            Item = new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = i.ToString(),
                Text = i.ToString()
            };
            List.Add(Item);
        }
        
        return new SelectList(List,"Value","Text");
    }
```

From the Controller:

```
    public ActionResult BEditPlayer(int ID)
    {
        Races_Players SelectedPlayer = _RaceRepository.GetPlayerBase(ID);

        ViewBag.MASelect = _RaceRepository.SelectListMA();
        ViewBag.STSelect = _RaceRepository.SelectListST();
        ViewBag.AGSelect = _RaceRepository.SelectListAG();
        ViewBag.PASelect = _RaceRepository.SelectListPA();
        ViewBag.AVSelect = _RaceRepository.SelectListAV();



        return View(SelectedPlayer);
    }
```

From the View: - as SelectList is to stop errors happening as the code is built

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MA, ViewBag.MASelect as SelectList, "Select One")
```

Also, for any new programmers as per the research and testing, `SelectList` and `SelectListItem` have `SelectedValue` and `Selected` respectively for selecting Default values.

`SelectedValue` can be any object that identifies the primary key of the list or a new default value of the list *(eg integer for a value already in the list, or a string for a default value of null)*.
`Selected`, however, is a boolean (ie true or false) that selects the value of the list.  You only need to use one or the other.

Remember - if the value is passed from the controller to the view as the value in `model => model.[Variable]` then the value will be set to the value passed, not to the value set by `SelectedValue` or `Selected`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax:

in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MA, ViewBag.MA,"Select One", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

in repository:

```
public SelectList SelectListMA(int MA)
    {
   var List = new List<SelectListItem>();
       
        for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
        {
           List.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = i.ToString(),
                Text = i.ToString(),
             });
           
        }
     return  new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text",MA);
}
```

But you  don't need to convert to List of SelectListItem  your existed lists.
Just use retun new SelectList(yourlist, "yourvalueproperty", "yourtextproperty",);

Comment: the code throws up two errors with this now:
in the controller: `"model" does not exist in this context`
in the view: `HTML helper does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor'`

Comment: Could you show your controller pls, and what MVC version are you using?

Comment: Question Edited

Comment: Show your view too then if it doesnt recognize @Html.DropDownListFor

Comment: Edited - all select lists are virtually the same, just the int values changed round

Comment: Do you have an error HTML helper does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor for all DDL?

Comment: not when using SelectList, when using just the list of selectListIitem the error does crop up

Comment: I changed a little , try again pls

Comment: Try to change IList<SelectListItem> SelectListMA(int MA) To List.

Comment: same issue - using SelectList the Drop down list is populating, but not selecting the selected value from the SelectListItem list; when changing to the proposed solution getting the same error.

Comment: I am really sorry, I was confused with different versions.  I made updates. Now it should be working.

Comment: Are you still using @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MA, new SelectList(ViewBag.MA, dataTextField: "Text", dataValueField:"Value")  or you use what I recomended  you? I don' t see any changes in SelectListMA